# Android SDK with eclipse but not opening up

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I downloaded the Android SDK with eclipse, but it won't open up. I also downloaded the jdk latest version, set paths, etc.but when I click android SDK application , it doesn't start. I tried to open it through eclipse, but it didn't open.
the SDK manager doesn't have an android icon. So, I think there's a problem with that application. Can anyone here give me the right solution ? Check out this screen shot : [image]

Comment: Open a DOS box, change directory to the one containing the SDK manager and invoke its executable from the command line. That should show you any errors arising.

Comment: ya.. i tried it.. check out this snapshot: http://imgur.com/ypAaoDv

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use its DOS 8.3 name to start it from the command line. First use the dir /X option to get the 8.3 representation, then run it using that name, like:

[image]

That will start it or show the error.